# Ext js get row spesific cell string value's first 4 elements

Tags: javascript, extjs, get, element

I want to get first 4 elements a cell value because I want to use an if statement.
I get cell value like below. 
**My code sample:**

```
var data = row.data;
if(data.MyStoreDataIndex=='something'){
 //TODO
 }
```

But, I want the first 4 elements because cell contents are the same only first 4 elements.
If I get what I want, I change my if statement. I don't want these with selected cell or selected row.

Comment: To clarify, Are you looking to do some condition with only the first 4 items within the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.MyStoreDataIndex.contains()

this is the solution :)